# Not reading data while it's printing

Tags: c#

While the printer job is running, I ran this program and it does not seem to pick up any data. But It works, If the program is already running before printing. Is this normal or I am doing something wrong?Please Advise?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string printerName = "Printer Name";
        string query = string.Format("SELECT * from Win32_Printer WHERE Name LIKE '%{0}'", printerName);
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not printing");

            ManagementObjectCollection coll = searcher.Get();
            var alreadyPrinting = false;
            foreach (ManagementObject printer in coll)
            {
                foreach (PropertyData property in printer.Properties)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", property.Name, property.Value)); //To check Printing information
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(printer.Properties["PrinterStatus"].Value) == 4 && !alreadyPrinting)
                    {

                        string printeroutput = "Printer is printing";
                        SpeechSynthesizer synthensizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
                        synthensizer.Volume = 100;
                        synthensizer.Rate = -2;

                        //Synchronous
                        synthensizer.Speak(printeroutput);
                        Console.Write(printeroutput);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        alreadyPrinting = true;
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: It is normal. Two action cannot executed same time in same thread.

Comment: Yus, I got that part but since it's looping and the Printer is continuously printing should not it eventually pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you 'allowed' to create more than one `SpeechSynthesizer`. It will create a `SpeechSynthesizer` every second if one of the printers is printing.

Is it possible to move the creation of the `SpeechSynthesizer` outside the while?

And when it is executing `synthensizer.Speak(printeroutput);` it will block your thread.

Comment: Yus, It is possible but the problem is not with SpeechSynthesizer, thanks.